# KDP class for latex and wrong margins

Tags: margins, document-classes, books

I am using latex with the [KDP class](https://github.com/JenniferMack/latex-kdp) to format my pdf.

The layout is overall very satisfying but the margins don't seem right. For example, on odd pages, the margin on the right side is wider than that on the left side. Vice versa for even pages.

It should be the opposite, since the left side of odd pages include the gutter, so I would expect the inner margin of the page to be wider.

Is there any way it can be fixed?

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{kdp}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
This should be $6\times9$ paper. lets see where this goes until the next margin and new line
\end{document}
```

Is there a relatively easy way to fix it?

EDIT: according to the document `Add the geometry package to have the PDF "trimmed" to the right size.`

[image: Page example]

Comment: This is a FAQ, you would expect the outer margins to be roughly twice the inner margin, so visually on a double page spread the three white areas have similar width.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, sorry I am not following. Do you have any references?

Comment: you are already using `geometry` and that allows you to specify space for binding the inner edges, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191697/1090

Comment: also https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-gutter

Comment: a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42063/1090 I guess

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you. The geometry package must be included along with the class, see the edit to my post.